# How to merge 3 list base on id in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have three list like this:

```
productData = [
  {
    'productId': 1000,
    'productName': 'Product 1000'
  },
  {
    'productId': 1001,
    'productName': 'Product 1001'
  }
]
stockData = [
  {
    'productId': 1000,
    'locationId': 1,
    'stock': 21
  },
  {
    'productId': 1000,
    'locationId': 2,
    'stock': 8
  },
  {
    'productId': 1001,
    'locationId': 1,
    'stock': 4
  },
  {
    'productId': 1001,
    'locationId': 2,
    'stock': 10
  }
]

locationData = [
  {
    'locationId': 1,
    'locationName': 'Location 1'
  },
  {
    'locationId': 2,
    'locationName': 'Location 2'
  }
]
```

and I want to merge it based on productId and locationId so it will be like this:

```
result = [
  {
    productName: 'Product 1000',
    stock: {
      total: 29,
      detail: [
        {
          locationName: 'Location 1',
          stock: 21
        },
        {
          locationName: 'Location 2',
          stock: 8
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    productName: 'Product 1001',
    stock: {
      total: 14,
      detail: [
        {
          locationName: 'Location 1',
          stock: 4
        },
        {
          locationName: 'Location 2',
          stock: 10
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I have done some code with ChainMap but the result is not like what I need,
Here is the result of my code:

```
[{'locationId': 1, 'locationName': 'Location 1', 'productId': 1000, 'stock': 21, 'productName': 'Product 1000'}, {'locationId': 2, 'locationName': 'Location 2'}]
```

First I grouped the productData and stockData which has productId, then from the result I grouped it with locationData which has the locationId, but the result is wrong,
can you please tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
grouped_subdicts = groupby(sorted(productData + stockData, key=itemgetter("productId")), itemgetter("productId"))

result = [dict(ChainMap(*g)) for k, g in grouped_subdicts]

grouped_subdicts_2 = groupby(sorted(result + locationData, key=itemgetter("locationId")), itemgetter("locationId"))
result_2 = [dict(ChainMap(*g)) for k, g in grouped_subdicts_2]

print(result_2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of groupby I'd use a more minimalistic solution with only `dict`s and `list`s involved, so you can better control your context:

```py
def make_product_entities(product_data):
    product_entities = {}
    for product in product_data:
        product_entities[product["productId"]] = {
            "productName": product["productName"],
            "stock": {"total": 0, "detail": []},
        }
    return product_entities


def make_location_entities(location_data):
    location_entities = {}
    for location in location_data:
        location_entities[location["locationId"]] = {
            "locationName": location["locationName"]
        }
    return location_entities


def accumulate_product_data(product_data, stock_data, location_data):

    product_entities = make_product_entities(product_data)
    location_entities = make_location_entities(location_data)

    for stock in stock_data:
        product_entity = product_entities[stock["productId"]]
        location_entity = location_entities[stock["locationId"]]

        product_entity["stock"]["total"] += stock["stock"]
        product_entity["stock"]["detail"].append(
            {"locationName": location_entity["locationName"], "stock": stock["stock"]}
        )

    return list(product_entities.values())
```

I use `make_product_entities` and `make_location_entities` to create lookup dictionaries for both product and location data.

Then in `accumulate_product_data` I create those lookup dictionaries, and then since `stock_data` is the association between location and product I loop through the stocks, mutate the product entities and then in the end of the accumulation I return only the values from the `product_entities` dictionary.

Try it and see if it fits your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would transform all three lists into dataframe, then use **groupby** and **pd.to_json** to have the final result

```
df_product = pd.DataFrame(productData,columns=['productId', 'productName'])
df_stock = pd.DataFrame(stockData,columns=['productId', 'locationId', 'stock'])
df_location = pd.DataFrame(locationData,columns=['locationId', 'locationName'])
```

Merge all these dfs to have a complete dataframe, add total stock per productName by using **groupby** and **transform**

```
df_merged_three_lists = df_stock.merge(df_product).merge(df_location)
df_merged_three_lists["total"] = df_merged_three_lists.groupby("productName", as_index=False)["stock"].transform('sum')
```

which will looks like below:

```
    productId   locationId  stock   productName     locationName    total
0   1000        1           21      Product 1000    Location 1      29
1   1000        2           8       Product 1000    Location 2      29
2   1001        1           4       Product 1001    Location 1      14
3   1001        2           10      Product 1001    Location 2      14
```

Then use **groupby** and **to_json** to have final result,

```
df_build_detail = df_merged_three_lists.groupby(["productName", "total"])[["locationName", "stock"]].apply(
lambda x: x.to_dict("records")).reset_index(name="detail")

result = df_build_detail.to_json(orient="records", force_ascii=False)
```

Result:

```
[{"productName":"Product 1000","total":29,"detail":[{"locationName":"Location 1","stock":21},{"locationName":"Location 2","stock":8}]},{"productName":"Product 1001","total":14,"detail":[{"locationName":"Location 1","stock":4},{"locationName":"Location 2","stock":10}]}]
```